# Deploy dockerized mysql container to edge device

Tags: mysql, azure, docker, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I have built a docker application using docker-compose which has mysql involved in it.I have pushed those containers to azure and wanted to deploy it in an edge device using Azure IoT Edge. For this i used docker application container and mysql container to deploy in edge device, Application is running but mysql is not running at edge device after deployment.

Here is the container create options that i have given for mysql module

Is it because as i am using the root as User? Which is refusing connection with different client.

```
{

"Env": [

"ACCEPT_EULA=Y",

"MSSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root"

],

"HostConfig": {

"PortBindings": {

  "13306/tcp": [

    {

      "HostPort": "13306"

    }

  ],

  "32000/tcp": [

    {

      "HostPort": "32000"

    }

  ]

},

"Mounts": [

  {

    "Type": "volume",

    "Source": "sqlVolume",

    "Target": "/var/lib/mysql"

  }

]

}
```

Comment: what is `iotedge list` showing? Also, can you maybe post the complete deployment manifest (without any credentials)?

Comment: You've shown us the Create Config that wraps a module, but you haven't shown us how you've composed your image and what the CMD you use to step into it and start things up.    Lastly, consider using _FILE business to keep your secret bits secret.  https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/